# The network BIOS command limit has been reached

Tags: windows, fileserver

My ASP.Net application gets files from a share folder on another windows server.
When requests are increased I get the following error:

`The network BIOS command limit has been reached`

I have followed the steps in the [Microsoft KB810886 article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/810886) but it has not solved my problem. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

I was having this same problem today on my Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise machine. What I did was enable the File Services role as follows:

1. Open up `Server Manager` (located in Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools)
2. Select the `Roles` node from the left pane
3. Select `Add Roles` from the main window, this will present you with a wizard
4. On the second page select `File Services` from the list of available roles then click next.
5. I chose to install `File Server`, `Services for Network File System`, `Windows Server 2003 File Services` and `Indexing Service`
6. Go ahead and install the role then restart your server (not sure a restart is necessary)

Comment: Can you add how to open server manager?  I've done it before, but forgot, and I'm sure others have been/will be in the same position.  Thanks!